# how to know smart contract gas price and gas limit when deploying the contract using web3j

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, web3j

I am new to smart contracts and ethereum I am using web3j to deploy contracts on the private network 
Following this as a guide 
https://github.com/web3j/web3j

In the below section of code, it asks for gas limit and gas price of the contract

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password", "/path/to/walletfile");

YourSmartContract contract = YourSmartContract.deploy(
        <web3j>, <credentials>,
        GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT,
        <param1>, ..., <paramN>).send();  // constructor params
```

how should I determine the `GAS_PRICE`, `GAS_LIMIT`? 
before that, I was using ethereum wallet to deploy contract it automatically estimates the gas price and limit. I am a beginner i do not know gow to estimate gas price and limit without ethereum wallet ?

Answer (score 2):

`Gas price` needs to be defined by you not too low to be picked up by the miners. It's basically a bidding war between you and the other people who want their transactions (including contract calls and contract deploys) mined.

`Gas limit` can be found out by first deploying the same contract on a test network or on one of the test networks. Make sure to add a bit more available gas (10%-20%) to make sure your transaction will not fail and you will not lose the transaction fee.